# How to animate areas of a D3 area chart?

Tags: animation, d3.js

How can d3 areas have their transitions animated? I've seen examples for lines but can't find anything on animating an area.

**Eg area:**

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```

**Update:** I've found an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060954) for an area chart but I don't understand it. How is this function creating the area transition?

```
function transition() {
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .data(function() {
        var d = layers1;
        layers1 = layers0;
        return layers0 = d;
      })
    .transition()
      .duration(2500)
      .attr("d", area);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The transition of `areas` works just like for other attributes. Only in case of areas, we are [interpolating strings](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolateString) instead of interpolating numbers. When you call the [area](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-_area) function with some `data`, then it produces a string which looks like `M0,213L4,214L9,215 ... L130,255.7`, which is a [DSL used for the `d` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData). When you change the `data` you pass to the `area` function, this string changes and D3 interpolates them.

Regarding the example you have found, the interesting bit which causes the transition is only this:

```js
    .transition()
      .duration(2500)
      .attr("d", area);
```

The other part merely is a fancy way of alternatively returning `layers1` and `layers0` as the `data` for the `area` function on consecutive calls.

```js
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .data(function() {
        var d = layers1;
        layers1 = layers0;
        return layers0 = d;
      })
```

Comment: The one u suggested isnt working 
    svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "area")
            .transition()
            .duration(3500)
            .attr("d", area)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @neptunemo for your suggestion. However, your code is too specific for your problem. I would like to take a general case for better illustration of your idea:

Please see the full code from an example of d3noob: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/119a138ef9bd1d8f0a8d57ea72355252

Original code of area generator:

```
var area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
```

Modified code of area generator:

```
var area = function(datum, boolean) {
    return d3.area()
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function (d) { return y(d.close); })
    .x(function (d) { return boolean ? x(d.date) : 0; })
    (datum);
}
```

- `datum` is to take the data,
- `boolean` is to control the:

  - `.x()` (in case you want the animation along x-axis)
  - `.y1()` (in case you want the animation along y-axis)

By setting boolean to `false`, we're able to set `.x()` or `.y1()` to `0`.

This will help us to set the initial state of area before triggering the transition process.

Modified code of area transition:

```
svg.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", d => area(d, false))
    .attr("fill", "lightsteelblue")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("d", d => area(d,true));
```

Effects?

- case of controlling `.x()`

[image]

- case of controlling `.y1()`

[image]

**Note**: The issue I met is that I cannot synchronize the animation of line and area :(

Answer (score 5):

Bit late to the party, but:

I solved the problem by modifying the original 'area' function, passing two variables: the data, and the field I wish to chart:

```
var area = function(datum, field) {
    return d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) {
            return xScale(d.period_end);
        })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) {
            return yScale(d[field] || 0);
        })(datum);
    };
```

Then when you draw the path, just use basic transition. First time, passing no 'field', resulting in drawing zero values, and then - after transition() - passing the field I wanted:

```
areaChart.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'area')
    .attr('d', area(chartData))
    .attr('fill', function() {
        return chartColor;
    })
    .attr('opacity', 0.15)
    .transition().duration(chartSettings.duration)
    .attr('d', area(chartData, 'value'));
```

Works nicely without the need for sub functions. Exactly the same can of course be done for line charts.