# Need to have two different colors in a linear gradient after a specific (x, y) point

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

with the line path & shadow's transition in sync. And I am able to do that with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65622588/8359178),

but I am trying to figure out a way to append the red color gradient area after a certain (x, y) point (in this case (48, 0)).

I filtered the graph data and have two arrays (x-axis points -> from 0 to 48 and from 48 to 60), but then don't know how to apply the data in `attrTween` function.

Here's the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxaus9?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Here's the shadow function:

```
    // Blue
    const colorArray1 = [
      ["rgb(8, 141, 218)", "0.8"],
      ["rgb(8, 141, 218)", "0.5"],
      ["rgb(23, 38, 65)", "0.3"]
    ];
    // Red
    const colorArray2 = [
      ["rgb(253, 17, 57)", "0.8"],
      ["rgb(253, 17, 57)", "0.4"],
      ["rgb(23, 38, 65)", "0.3"]
    ];
    const id: string = isShadowBefore48Hr ? "grad1" : "grad2";
    const data: Array<{}> = isShadowBefore48Hr
      ? this.graphData.filter(d => d.hrCount <= 48)
      : this.graphData.filter(d => d.hrCount >= 48);
    const angle: number = isShadowBefore48Hr ? -15 : 0;

    const defs = this.g.append("defs");
    const grad = defs
      .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", id)
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("x2", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "0%")
      .attr("y2", "100%")
      .attr("gradientTransform", "rotate(" + angle + ")");
    grad
      .selectAll("stop")
      .data(isShadowBefore48Hr ? colorArray1 : colorArray2)
      .enter()
      .append("stop")
      .style("stop-color", (d: any) => {
        return d[0];
      })
      .style("stop-opacity", (d: any) => {
        return d[1];
      })
      .attr("offset", (d: any, i: any) => {
        return 100 * (i / 2) + "%";
      });
    const area = d3
      .area()
      .y0(this.height)
      .y1((d: any) => d.y)
      .x((d: any) => d.x);
    this.g
      .append("path")
      .attr("fill", "url(#" + id + ")")
      .transition()
      .duration(5000)
      .attrTween("d", (d: any) => {
        const line = d3.select(".line").node(); // Find the line graph
        const length = line.getTotalLength(); // Get length
        const i = d3.interpolate(0, length); // Interpolator function over length
        const dataPoints = []; // Array to hold accumulated data points
        return (t: any) => {
          dataPoints.push(line.getPointAtLength(i(t))); // On every iteration, get a point on the line
          return area(dataPoints);
        };
      });
  }
```

Comment: I have played with your stackblitz chart. Whatever I have done the path is the same for both desired gradients (e.g. full multiline from 0 to max. value). So you need to change the way you add a path (probably two) since your function to show animated gradient will respect - guessing but strong feel about it - only the second gradient and of course full path data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment you should have clear two paths (as you can't have only one gradient for both) and maybe reveal the chart by adding a clip path (of the entire chart area) that changes its width from 0 to chart width, essentially showing a chart in transition. This is old code for D3.js version4, slightly adapted with your gradients (you'll figure the rest out):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

pre#data {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="data">
date,close
1-May-12,58.13
30-Apr-12,53.98
27-Apr-12,67.00
26-Apr-12,89.70
25-Apr-12,99.00
24-Apr-12,130.28
23-Apr-12,166.70
20-Apr-12,234.98
19-Apr-12,345.44
18-Apr-12,443.34
17-Apr-12,543.70
16-Apr-12,580.13
13-Apr-12,605.23
12-Apr-12,622.77
11-Apr-12,626.20
10-Apr-12,628.44
9-Apr-12,636.23
5-Apr-12,633.68
4-Apr-12,624.31
3-Apr-12,629.32
2-Apr-12,618.63
30-Mar-12,599.55
29-Mar-12,609.86
28-Mar-12,617.62
27-Mar-12,614.48
26-Mar-12,606.98
</pre>
<script>
    let animationDuration = 5000;
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 720 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // parse the date / time
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // define the area
    var area = function(datum, boolean) {
      return d3.area()
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) {
          return boolean ? y(d.close) : y(d.close);
        })
        .x(function(d) {
          return boolean ? x(d.date) : 0;
        })
        (datum);
    }

    // define the line
    var valueline = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.close);
      });

    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var defs = svg.append("defs");

    var clip = defs.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip");
    var clipRect = clip.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 0)
      .attr("height", height);

// Blue
  const colorArray1 = [
    ["rgb(8, 141, 218)", "0.8"],
    ["rgb(8, 141, 218)", "0.5"],
    ["rgb(23, 38, 65)", "0.3"]
  ];
  // Red
  const colorArray2 = [
    ["rgb(253, 17, 57)", "0.8"],
    ["rgb(253, 17, 57)", "0.4"],
    ["rgb(23, 38, 65)", "0.3"]
  ];

  function addGradient(isShadowBefore48Hr) {
      const id = isShadowBefore48Hr ? "grad1" : "grad2";
        const angle = isShadowBefore48Hr ? -15 : 0;
        const grad = defs
        .append("linearGradient")
        .attr("id", id)
        .attr("x1", "0%")
        .attr("x2", "0%")
        .attr("y1", "0%")
        .attr("y2", "100%")
            .attr("gradientTransform", "rotate(" + angle + ")");    
        grad
      .selectAll("stop")
      .data(isShadowBefore48Hr ? colorArray1 : colorArray2)
      .enter()
      .append("stop")
      .style("stop-color", (d) => {
        return d[0];
      })
      .style("stop-opacity", (d) => {
        return d[1];
      })
      .attr("offset", (d, i) => {
        return 100 * (i / 2) + "%";
      });
  }

  addGradient(true);
  addGradient(false);

    var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("pre#data").text());

    data.reverse();

    // format the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.close;
    })]);

    // add first area
    svg.append("path")
      .data([data.filter(function(item) { return item.date <= parseTime("23-Apr-12") } ) ])
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", d => area(d, true))
      //.attr("fill", "lightsteelblue")
    .attr("fill", "url(#" + "grad1" + ")")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    // add second area
    svg.append("path")
      .data([data.filter(function(item) { return item.date >= parseTime("23-Apr-12") } ) ])
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", d => area(d, true))
      //.attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("fill", "url(#" + "grad2" + ")")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    // add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline)
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    // add the X Axis
/*  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
*/
    // add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    clipRect.transition()
      .duration(5000)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .attr("width", width)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt, I tried to follow your code but seems not to be working. Can you please check it once. Here's the code [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxaus9?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Thanks

Comment: I believe one other developer will jump in - first look is that you still have only one path, not two (based on value separation). So create both but with same full (graphData) ranges for axes and scale (and use your variables, I hardcoded "grad1" etc .The clip rectangle is then just easy to animate as you have - it's just a clipping area for the entire chart that expands from 0 to full width.